# Using Azure Logic App how to mention a tag name into a channel created in MS Teams

Tags: azure, microsoft-teams, azure-logic-apps, azure-logic-app-standard

I have a existing MS Teams and I have created a tags and added few users under that tags. Now I have created an Azure Logic App which will take the input from web and create a new channel under the existing MS Teams. Now, I am trying to post a message into the newly created channel but here I want to mention my tags which I have already created. So, far I have tried below options:

1. Get an @mention token for a user -> Using this option I have defined my tag name, but it is not working.
2. Using Post a message in a chat or channel action I tried to define @tag name but it does not work.
3. Then using same action mentioned in point #2, I tried to use `<at>tag name</at>` but still no luck and it just print the message into the channel.

Any other steps are there to post the tags into channel?

Comment: Could you please share what type of channel you are creating (public or private)? Tags are not yet supported in private channels.
Could you please go through below doc which mention how to create and use tags.
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/microsoftteams/manage-tags

Comment: @Nivedipa-MSFT - I have created a tags in my MS Teams manually. Now, I want to mention this tag in my teams channel using Azure Logic App. So, from the documentation it seems there is no direct way to mention tags into a channel using Azure logic App and for that I can use rest API to mention the tags. Now the problem is how I can find the tags ID available in my MS Teams using rest API?

Comment: Using [List teamworkTags](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/api/teamworktag-list?view=graph-rest-beta&tabs=http#http-request) API you can get the tags ID.
It's in beta version so you can not use it for production apps.

Answer (score 0):

For more visibility adding answer from comment section.

There is no direct way to mention tags into a channel using Azure logic App. Using rest API its possible to mention the tags.

Reference doc for creating and using tags.
[Manage Tags](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/microsoftteams/manage-tags)

You can get the list of Tags Id using following API
**/teams/{team-Id}/tags**